# Deleting media using the Wordpress Rest API

Tags: media, rest-api, api, wp-api

I am trying to delete a media object from my Wordpress instance using the Wordpress API in Postman.

I'm having trouble finding the endpoint according to the documentation.

Here is my http method and  route:

`DELETE {{site}}/wp-json/wp/v2/media/{{mediaId}}?force=1`

I keep getting route not found however:

```
{
    "code": "rest_no_route",
    "message": "No route was found matching the URL and request method",
    "data": {
        "status": 404
    }
}
```

This is how I'm trying to call it generated in curl:

```
curl -X DELETE \
  http://<site>/<subsite>/wp-json/wp/v2/media/?force=1 \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Authorization: Basic <token>' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Content-Length: ' \
  -H 'Host: <Host IP>' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: <Postman-Token>' \
  -H 'User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.15.2' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
```

Following the documentation for the delete endpoint.

> https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/media/

Comment: But looking at the cURL request, you didn't specify the media ID: `http://<site>/<subsite>/wp-json/wp/v2/media/?force=1` ?

Comment: Yeah I caught that. Postman isn't populating my value correctly.

Comment: FIXED: Postman had double variable names in it's environment. Deleted the empty one and populated the last one. IT WORKS!

Comment: Well, to be honest, I don't use Postman.. and I think you should write that into an answer. It might help someone having similar issue (in the future). :)

Comment: yes  definitely will do thank you!